# Original is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

On the 28th of August, i created [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/wallet-initialization-failed-basic-stringresize) including detailed logs. I followed up by creating [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/1019), reporting another bug (wrong compilation of win32) and following up with the issue ever since (multiple pushes in the ticket and reddit). So far, due to the win32 version still not being updated, there is no confirmed solution to the issue, thats why i didnt answer my own question.

Three days later, someone else created a post for [the same question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/basic-stringresize-crash) to which [user36303](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/22/user36303) answered with the current status of my github issue.

Now i noticed that my question was closed as a duplicate of the later questions, which doesnt make any sense to me: Mine was first, i created the issue, i am tracking and pushing it and so far we dont have any confirmation for the cause of the issue (even though the miscompilation is the most likely issue). It would make sense flagging the later question as a duplicate and linking to my question, but not the other way around.

Comment: For the future: closing as duplicate allows us only to mark the answered question as original not vice versa. However, since your question is of a better quality, I decided to merge the threads into one, this means your question is now answered. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you asked the question first but I do not see anything inherently wrong with what happened for the following reasons:

1. The [GitHub issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1019) you opened was created after the [second question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/basic-stringresize-crash) was asked. It appears as if the duplicate question was generated independently of yours (no intent to steal your question).
2. When there is a duplicate, preserving answers is sometimes more important than preserving the question that was asked first. Since your question was never answered (before being closed as a duplicate) and the second question did have an answer there is a reasonable basis for which question was closed.
3. If your objection is primarily about "fairness" or SE reputation I would suggest you do the following:

Provide a better answer to the question that remains open when it becomes available since you have stated you believe there is not yet a confirmed solution to your problem.

In the future, feel free to answer your own question even prior to the solution being 100% complete. You can always return to edit your answer later to make it more complete.

Comment: Regarding 2: Thats why i said that there is no answer yet, the other answer is a "maybe" as the problem is not confirmed yet. So both remain unanswered as i wish to update it after the solution can be confirmed, to make it a real answer. Now that its closed, i cant.